# How to get all options from ul li drop-down using Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The project that I am working on changes drop-down lists from simple ones to ul li. Prior to this to scrap all options from a drop down list I would do the following:

```
myList = [] 
el = browser.find_element_by_id('Filter_ClientDistrict')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    myList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
```

How can scrap all the options from the same drop down list if its code looks like this now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Filter_ClientDistrict button.dropdown-toggle').click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Filter_ClientDistrict ul li"))
    myList = [] 
    el = browser.find_element_by_id('Filter_ClientDistrict')
    for option in el.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul li'):
        myList.append(option.get_attribute("innerText").strip())
```

Comment: I am getting an empty list. Am I supposed to replace the CSS selector from 'ul li' to something else?

Comment: No, you don't need to replace it. I guess the list will be added only when you click on the dropdown button. Can you show the HTML code o the dropdown button when the list is collapsed?

Comment: I figured that might be the reason. So I added an action to open the drop-down list before I run your code, but I am still getting an empty list.

Comment: I've updated the answer to click and wait. Could you try?

Comment: This is the error that I get now: `Error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'trim'` I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Sorry. In the last line, it should be `.strip()` instead of `.trim()`

Comment: Now I started getting `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document' error. It is my understanding that it is because JS doesn't load the drop-down list completely. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @sprogissd from my experience, there are 3 choices.  1. Add time.sleep for a couple seconds after click on the button. 2. Try/catch. Do it again when an error occurred. 3. Use default wait with try/catch. Wait until it finishes the loop without an error. I prefer choice #1. Choice #3 is for a large number of elements like 20,000 cells in a table.